# Ошибка при установке Composer - не найден libsybcs64.dll

Tags: php, apache, веб-программирование, composer

Доброго времени суток.
Проблема: 
Установил PHP и Apache, пытаясь поставить Composer, получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Была та же ошибка также с OCI.dll, но избавился, закомментировав пару строк в php.ini.

Как быть с этим libsybcs64.dll ?

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно также. Уберите из файла php.ini подключение плагина sybase. Ещё можно тут почитать о [проблеме](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46480&edit=3), возможно, стоит обновить вашу версию php